# SAP ABAP Layer Aware Debugging not Available

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I am working on SAP SMARTFORMS application.

To debug SMARTFORMS I assigned a breakpoint on the function module that the SMARTFORMS generates.

When I run SMARTFORMS, I get the debugger, however the debugger does not have the option for Layer Aware Debugging.

Layer Aware Debugging Option on system other than mine: Configure Debugger Layer

[image]

On my system, missing Layer Aware Debugging button:
[image]

My system configuration:
[image]

Comment: Obviously, you are running an old version where ABAP Layer Aware Debugging is not available. So, just upgrade your system. What is your question?